# PhoneGap (Cordova) offline event listener not working

Tags: cordova, connection, offline

I want to detect offline status in PhoneGap. After installing the Network Information plugin, I added this code:

```
    function onOnline () {
        console.log('You are online'); 
    }
    function onOffline () {
        console.log('You are offline'); 
    }
    function bootApp() {
        /* App initialization logic */ 
    }

    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', bootApp, false);
```

The online event fires, but the offline event does not fire. At first I thought it was because I needed to place the offline / online event listeners inside deviceready. I tried this and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Current connection plugin used something like the following to detect network

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

    function checkConnection() {
        if(navigator.connection.type==0)
        {
            alert("Offline");
        }
        else if(navigator.connection.type=='none')
        {
            alert("Offline");

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Online");

        }
    }
```

You can see details here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the network information plugin to your config.xml file for phonegap ver 3 and up.

```
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
```